# Send Jira Issue Description text as ADF table in Jira REST API

Tags: jira

I am trying to update an issue description by sending an ADF table. My javascript code is as follows.

```
    {
    "fields" : {
        "description": {
    "version": 1,
    "type": "doc",
    "content": [
      {
  "type": "table",
  "attrs": {
    "isNumberColumnEnabled": false,
    "layout": "default"
  },
  "content": [
    {
      "type": "tableRow",
      "content": [
        {
          "type": "tableCell",
          "attrs": {},
          "content": [
            {
              "type": "paragraph",
              "content": [
                {
                  "type": "text",
                  "text": " Row one, cell one"
                }]
              }]
            },
          {
            "type": "tableCell",
            "attrs": {},
            "content": [
                {
              "type": "paragraph",
              "content": [
                {
                  "type": "text",
                  "text": "Row one, cell two"
                } ]
              }]
            }]
          }]
        }]
      }
    }
  }
```

The error that I get back is "description":"Operation value must be a string". Not sure what I am doing wrong as it looks like I have the ADF formatting correct.

This is calling jira cloud via the rest api.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. The URL must be version 3 of the API. Just have "latest" will not work. Example:

```
https://mycompay.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/45379
```

and not

```
https://mycompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/latest/issue/45379
```